# Infiniband HCA, Physical State is stuck Disabled

Tags: centos, infiniband

While setting up a point-to-point infiniband connection between two servers, I ran the command `ibportstate -G [my port GUID] disable`. Now when I try to get the port polling, or do anything with the device at all, I get the following error.

```
[user@server1 ~]$ perfquery -vvv -ddd
ibwarn: [16059] umad_init: umad_init
ibwarn: [16059] umad_open_port: ca (null) port 0
ibwarn: [16059] umad_get_cas_names: max 32
ibwarn: [16059] umad_get_cas_names: return 1 cas
ibwarn: [16059] resolve_ca_name: checking ca 'qib0'
ibwarn: [16059] resolve_ca_port: checking ca 'qib0'
ibwarn: [16059] umad_get_ca: ca_name qib0
ibwarn: [16059] umad_get_ca: opened qib0
ibwarn: [16059] resolve_ca_port: checking port 0
ibwarn: [16059] resolve_ca_port: checking port 1
ibwarn: [16059] resolve_ca_port: checking port 0
ibwarn: [16059] resolve_ca_port: checking port 1
ibwarn: [16059] resolve_ca_name: phys found -1 on (null) port 0
ibwarn: [16059] umad_open_port: opening mthca0 port 1
ibwarn: [16059] mad_rpc_open_port: can't open UMAD port ((null):0)
perfquery: iberror: [pid 16059] main: failed: Failed to open '(null)' port '0'
```

Any command that interacts with the infiniband device responds with the exact same output, no exceptions. The physical state of the port is just stuck.

```
[user@server1 ~]$ cat /sys/class/infiniband/qib0/ports/1/phys_state 
3: Disabled
```

And here's the state on the other server so I know it's at least trying.

```
[user@server0 ~]$ cat /sys/class/infiniband/qib0/ports/1/phys_state 
2: Polling
```

I've rebooted, restarted opensm, and even pulled and replaced the card. The second machine in the pair is hosting services that I can't take offline any time soon, so I can't switch the HCAs.

I've read a few other threads on various websites describing a similar issue, but none of them were resolved in the thread.

QLogic IBA7322

CentOS 7, Kernel 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64

infiniband-diags 1.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem by switching the cable, even though the one I was using was working beforehand. Then I switched back and it worked again. I had tried unplugging the cable at both ends and reconnecting it, but that hadn't worked. I know QSFP and SFP DAC cables and pluggables have some electrical bits on them, but I have no clue how they work so I can't say for sure what went wrong.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the question has been closed... I had exactly the same problem and  this fixed it finally: `mlxfwreset -d <device> -l 3 reset`. The command is part of the Mellanox Firmware Tools (MFT) package.